# populate table in django template using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, knockout.js

This is the first time I am trying my hands on Knockout javascript. I am very naive to it so excuse me for the question.

I have a view which gives a json response.

**views.py**

```
    def get(self, request, code, format=None):
        data = self.get_details(code)
        paginator = Paginator(data, self.paginate_by)
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        context = {}
        try:
            data_sent = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            data_sent = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            data_sent = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context['data'] = self.get_user(chain_code)        
        context['page_object'] = data_sent.object_list
        context['code'] = code
        data = json.dumps(context, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        return HttpResponse(data)
```

I want to use this response to populate **context['data']** in a table in my django template something like this:

```
Id  Name  Status

1   xyz    1
2   abc    2
```

**datalist.html**

```
    <script src="{% static "jsscript/datalist.js" %} "></script>

        <div class = "container">
           <div class = "page-header">


 <!---all headers data --->
       </div>
       <div class="tab-content">
           <table class="table table-bordered listingtable" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th style="width: 10%;">Id</th>
                      <th style="width: 10%;">Name</th>
                      <th style="width: 20%;">Status</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>    

              <tbody>
               <!----script to populate table--->

             </tbody>
        </table>
```

I have gone through the official tutorial of knockout.js, but I'm not sure how to access the response from my API and populate the table in the template.

What I have tried so far:

**datalist.js**

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.status = ko.observable(data.status);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
```

I know this solution is completely wrong but I'm just not sure how to proceed in the right path, Can someone just enlighten me about it?

Answer (score 2):

Below is showing how to populate your data as table in knockout when you get your data from the server (you may use Ajax).

Example:https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/108/

HTML:

```
   <table class="table table-bordered listingtable" >
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th >Id</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Status</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>    
     <tbody data-bind="foreach:YourArrayList">
       <tr>
         <td data-bind="text:Id"></td> 
         <td data-bind="text:Name"></td>
         <td data-bind="text:Status"></td>
       </tr>                  
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

JS:

```
var yourData = [{id:1,name:"AAA" ,status:"AAA-status" },{id:2,name:"BBB" ,status:"BBB-status" },{id:3,name:"CCC" ,status:"CCC-status" }];

var MainViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.YourArrayList= ko.observableArray();
    self.YourArrayList($.map(yourData, function (item) {
             return new StatusItemViewModel (item);
        }));
};
var StatusItemViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.Status = ko.observable(data.status);
};

ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel ());
```

Comment: what if the response from view is not an array but json? @Matt.kaaj ?

Comment: Based on what you've shown on your question(2 rows) I used  an array of `JSON` objects. if your server only sends a single `JSON object` then  you don't need to map over your data, you don't need to have an `observableArray`,  you can't use `foreach` in a table. Take a look at this  https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/112/